# vim with only python3

Tags: python, vim

I install this morning the vim8.0 version from the github
http://www.vim.org/download.php

when launching vim and trying `:echo has("python3")` it returns `0` (same for python)

After installing it and typing `vim --version | grep python` I get:

```
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python/dyn      +vreplace
+cscope          +lispindent      +python3/dyn     +wildignore
```

looks like there could be problems if there is `+python` and `+python3` but is it the case with the `/dyn` ?
Following this i tried a lot of things to only have only python3

```
        ./configure --with-features=huge 
        --enable-multibyte \
        --enable-rubyinterp=yes \
        --enable-python3interp=yes \
        --with-python3-config-dir=/usr/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m-x86_64-linux-gnu \
        --enable-perlinterp=yes \
        --enable-gui=gtk2 --enable-cscope --prefix=/usr \
        --disable-pythoninterp \
```

(and many other commands...) but i cannot manage to get echo has("python3") return 1.

also tried to remove vim 8.0 and no way to remove it ...

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30444890/vim-use-python3-interpreter-in-python-mode/30449124#30449124 is relevant

Answer (score 0):

That last line in your configure command:

```
    --disable-pythoninterp \
```

is not a valid option.  The valid option for Python interpreter is

```
    --enable-pythoninterp \
```

the default value of which is no, and the optional values are no/yes/dynamic.

(see vim80/src/auto/configure, line 1486; and vim80/src/configure.in, line 1100)

So, it looks like it's worth trying to remove that last line and re-issue the configure command.