# Installed pandas, but still get an import error when running code

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Ubuntu Linux server, and I am trying to use pandas, but I wrote code in a vim file, and when I try to run it, it says import error, no module pandas found. But if I open up an python3 environment, then it works. Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Make sure vim is using Python 3: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30444890/vim-use-python3-interpreter-in-python-mode

Comment: Most likely you installed pandas for Python 3 and vim is using Python 2.